# The word bound in "osaka bound"

Tags: meaning

Can anyone tell me what does the word "bound" mean in here: "Osaka bound"?

Thanks!

Comment: More context would be appropriate here.

Comment: It means "on the way to".

Comment: And Osaka more or less rhymes with Morocco. "Morocco bound" is a pun on "on the way to Morocco" and "held together with supple Morocco leather, like an expensive book" which was popularized by the movie "The Road to Morocco" and its sequels.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you indicate your initial research, so that we do not duplicate efforts. At a minimum, what did a dictionary lookup of *bound* turn up for you, and why was it not sufficient to answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bound):

> **bound**: intending to go : going
>   *bound for home*,  *college-bound*

Also used in the title of the song *[Homeward Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeward_Bound_(song))*.